# Reference the text field that I'm in when I press enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, keycode

Javascript/jQuery (doesn't work how I want it to):

```
function chkKey(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        $(this).val("value", "wow such code");
    };
};
```

**I do not want to reference the text field by name** because I will have multiple text fields on the page with different names that use the same chkKey function. I need to reference the text field that I'm currently in regardless of name. Is this possible? I'm thinking it's a parent/bubbling issue, but I don't have experience with those things at all.

**EDIT:** Complete HTML/JS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Boxes and Lines</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="outerDiv">
        <input type="button" name="btnNewField" value="Add New Field" onclick="appendNewField()">
        <p></p>
        <div id="mainDiv"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        function chkKey(event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                $(this).val("value", "wow");
            };
        };

        // returns a text field object
        function txtField(fieldName, fieldVal){
            var objTxtField = document.createElement("input");
            $(objTxtField).attr({
                type: "text",
                name: fieldName,
                value: fieldVal,
                onkeyup: "chkKey(event)"
            });
            return objTxtField;
        };

        // if there is no appended text field, create one and give it focus
        function appendNewField() {
            if ($("#mainDiv").find('[name="appTxtField"]').length === 0 ) {
                $(new txtField("appTxtField", "")).appendTo($("#mainDiv")).focus();
            };
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you add complete HTML

Comment: Full HTML/JS code added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors in your code:

- Using `val` like it was `attr` or `prop`, but it expects only one parameter
- Trying add a `keyup` event handler with `attr`, and you should be using `on`

Take a look at your code below, fixed with the items above:

```js
function chkKey(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        $(this).val("wow such code");
    };
};

// returns a text field object
function txtField(fieldName, fieldVal){
    var objTxtField = document.createElement("input");
    $(objTxtField).attr({
        type: "text",
        name: fieldName,
        value: fieldVal
    }).on('keyup', chkKey);
  
    return objTxtField;
};


// if there is no appended text field, create one and give it focus
function appendNewField() {
    if ($("#mainDiv").find('[name="appTxtField"]').length === 0 ) {
        $(new txtField("appTxtField", "")).appendTo($("#mainDiv")).focus();
    };
};

appendNewField()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`onkeyup: "chkKey(event, this)"` will pass the current element to the function.

Comment: I didn't know this was possible. I will definitely use this in the future.